# Force usage of webpack-dev-server 2.9.4 instead 2.7.0

Tags: yarnpkg, laravel-mix

Some packages of laravel 5 such [Spoon](https://github.com/spatie/spoon) can with a package.json and when run yarn get error

`yarn install v1.3.2
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/webpack-dev-server/-/webpack-dev-server-2.7.0.tgz: Request failed \"404 Not Found\"".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/abkrim/Sites/spoon/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.`

I see a regresion of version 2.7.0 of webpack-dev-server. Only possible use 2.7.1 or up.

I read my package.json

`{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "css-lint": "stylelint \"resources/assets/css/**/*.css\" --fix",
    "js-lint": "eslint resources/assets/js --ext .js,.vue --fix && exit 0",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-config-spatie": "^2.0.1",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "postcss-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss-easy-import": "^2.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^8.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
  }
}`

Any way for solution this headache?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command ?

```
yarn add -D webpack-dev-server@2.9.4
```